# Detached Head while building pipeline on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, git-detached-head

I notice the following during the pipeline build stage for my git branch. I however get no 'HEAD DETACHED' error when I checkout the branch in my dev environment. Is this error significant or is it just something that is to be expected for all git based pipeline builds on Azure DevOps?

> Note: switching to 'd1be2f5491ae7fbb40fc7ec095c4be44b4120dc5'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by switching
>   back to a branch.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
>   may do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
>
> git switch -c
>
> Or undo this operation with:
>
> git switch -
>
> Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to
>   false
>
> HEAD is now at d1be2f5 Update azure-pipelines.yml for Azure Pipelines

Comment: When the agent download the git repo it always will be on detach HEAD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an error, which is why it's not reported as an error, doesn't appear with scary red text, and doesn't stop the build.

It is expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It is an expected behavior, a kind of temporary Git state. For our project it corrupted the build info we keep in binary, we lost the branch information. Starting the build pipeline with

```
git checkout <branch>
git pull
```

fixed that. Wonder why pull is necessary, otherwise it's 1 commit behind HEAD.